# Prove that the function $f(x)=x \ln x$ is not a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Prove that the function $f(x)=x \ln x$ is not a polynomial

My thought process is that I know polynomials have specific properties when I take the derivative. Namely, for $f(x)=x^n$ the derivative is $f^{'}(x)=nx^{n-1}$. That or $f(x)=0$ and that derivative is equal to $0$ (itself).
I know that $f^{'}(x)=\ln(x) + 1$ which is not a degree less that $f(x)$ and which doesn't equal f(x). Therefore, I have that $f(x)=x\ln x$ is not a polynomial.
How accurate is this proof? I feel like the proof is clunky, but can't get a finger on what the issue is.

Comment: its not a polynomial because its not defined for $x<0$?

Comment: You could use logic relating to the Big-O bounds on the function, and prove that it is between a linear and a quadratic, and therefore cannot be a polynomial...

Comment: You are already on the right track when thinking derivatives. Hint: suppose it's a polynomial with order $n$, what happens to the $(n+1)^{st}$ derivative of $f(x)$?

Comment: It would equal to zero, but in this function that never happens. However, isn't that not exactly a fact we can rely on given that $x^{-2}$ is a polynomial and it never gets to $0$?

Comment: Ah. That was a mental slip up for sure. Thank you for clarifying that issue

Comment: So, with your hint are you implying that since the second derivative doesn't get me to 0 it can't be a polynomial, or is it since we get $x^{-1}$ as the 3rd derivative and we never get to 0?

Comment: $\forall n \in \mathbb N, f^{(n)}(x) \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment section, one way to prove it is that if the order of the polynomial is $n$ then $f^{(n+1)}(x) \equiv 0$ which we can  easily verify is not the case.

Another way, based on the solution of [Luna145](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/852226/luna145), is as follows:

Suppose $f(x)$ is an order-$n$ polynomial, then

$$\ln x^2 = 2 \ln x \implies f(x^2)=x^2\ln x^2 = 2x \cdot x\ln x = 2x f(x).$$

Compare the order of both sides we have $$2n=1+n \implies n=1 \implies x \ln x = ax+b$$
which is absurd.

Answer (score 2):

First off, it's not a polynomial because it's not defined for $x \leq 0$. If you mean for $x > 0$, then you can go as follows:

Assume $x\log x$ is a polynomial.

$$x\log x = a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_1x+a_0$$

$$\Rightarrow \log x = a_nx^{n-1} + a_{n-1}x^{n-2}+...+a_1+\frac{a_0}{x}$$

Use the fact that $g(x) = \log x$ satisfies $f(x^2) = 2f(x)$ by log laws:

$$\Rightarrow a_nx^{2n-2} + a_{n-1}x^{2n-4} + ... +a_1x^2+\frac{a_0}{x^2} = 2a_nx^{n-1}+2a_{n-1}x^{n-2}+...+2a_1 + \frac{2a_0}{x}$$

Compare coefficients. This means $\log x = 0$ for all $x$, which is nonsense.  There's many ways to do it, but here's strictly from the definition of a polynomial.

Comment: +1. You might want to change $f$ to $g$ because $f$ is already defined in the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will change that